# GCM class cast exception

Tags: java, android, google-cloud-messaging

```
if (GooglePlayServicesUtil.isUserRecoverableError(resultCode)) {
        GooglePlayServicesUtil.getErrorDialog(resultCode, (Activity)  
     context, PLAY_SERVICES_RESOLUTION_REQUEST).show();
    }
```

Exception:

> java.lang.ClassCastException: com.interconnect.garhoud.Garhoud
>   cannot   be  cast to android.app.Activity    at
>   com.interconnect.library.gcm.Util.checkPlayServices(Util.java:96)
>         at     com.interconnect.library.gcm.Regiseter.handleRegister(Regiseter.java:53)
>   at 
>   com.interconnect.library.gcm.Regiseter.onHandleIntent(Regiseter.java:30)
>   at       android.app.IntentService$ServiceHandler.handleMessage
>   (IntentService.java:65)    at
>   android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)    at
>   android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:146)    at
>   android.os.HandlerThread.run(HandlerThread.java:61)

I have used context as getApplicationContext, because I have called that if from an intent service. How can I handle this exception?

Comment: Great resource, by developers for developers solely based around ClassCastException. https://github.com/mopub/mopub-android-sdk/issues/13.

Comment: look at the error log and see it say that you cannot cast to Activity and still you are casting it to Activity

Comment: I dont have an activity instance to use in that method because i called it from a class that extended from an IntentService and it works most of the devices but recently i found this error in  fabric

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you cannot show a dialog from a service, you can instead use [GooglePlaySErvicesUtil.showErrorNotification()](http://developer.android.com/reference/com/google/android/gms/common/GooglePlayServicesUtil.html#showErrorNotification(int,%20android.content.Context)), which allows you to post a notification prompting the user to resolve the error with Google Play Services.